# How to show the Site Name specifically on the document library landing page?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

One of the Project I am working on, I have a requirement to show the site name on the document library page so that the user is aware about the site he/she is working on.

Also I want the site name to appear only on the Document Library page level. I believe if this is done at the master page level by leveraging the breadcrumb but then it would reflect everywhere in the navigation so want to make sure that it reflects only on the document library page.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this? I am working with Office 365/SharePoint online. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modern UI (site name should already be there) or the Classic UI?

Comment: Hi Mike, Yes its there in the modern UI but how to make that work for the Classic UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code to add for updating every page where the Site Title is not displayed. (Classic UI SP 2013, 2016 and Online only) This has one more IF statement than the previous example that checks to see if the site title is already displayed.

```
<script>
function TTNAddSiteTitle() {

  if( document.querySelector("#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").innerText.trimRight() != ctx.SiteTitle) {

    // if(ctx.listTemplate == "101" ) {
      document.querySelector("#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin",ctx.SiteTitle + " - ");
    // }
  }
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("TTNAddSiteTitle");
</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately I still see the site title being displayed twice on the landing page after updating the code as you mentioned in the master page.

Comment: I got it backwards... change == to !=.  I updated the example above.

Comment: Yeah I sort of did not notice that before, that worked, thanks a lot Mike.

Comment: Mike, what if I want to also display the site title on a created custom list in addition to the Document library page (this is not a requirement but asking for info purpose). I tried tweaking the if condition and replaced as if(ctx.listTemplate == "101" && ctx.listTemplate == "100") but that did not work and it also removed the site title on the document library page. Thanks.

Comment: Change && to ||.   I.e. from AND to OR.

Comment: I have this code applied in the Master page and it does the job and works fine when tested on Chrome and Firefox. When users tested in IE, it does not work and when clicked on the Library tab in the ribbon, the ribbon disappears and IE does not show site name on the document library page. To troubleshoot this, I took off the above code from master page, then ribbon started working fine in IE and users were able to access open with explorer. So is there a workaround to make this code work for IE? Microsoft did not have an answer when I troubleshooted with them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Several options, but most will add text to a SPAN in the page using a pattern like this:

```
document.querySelector("#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea span").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin","Your Site Name - ")
```

You can have it pull the site name from the context (ctx.SiteTitle):

```
document.querySelector("#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea span").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin",ctx.SiteTitle + " - ")
```

A full script block:

```
<script>
function TTNAddSiteTitle() {
  document.querySelector("#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin",ctx.SiteTitle + " - ");
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("TTNAddSiteTitle");
</script>
```

Now the question is where do you put the script...

- In the view page. Edit each view page using SharePoint Designer, click the Advance Mode button, and add the code above just after "</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>".
- In a Content Editor Web Part added to each view page. While the easiest, the problem with this one is that the page will not display the FILE and LIBRARY ribbons until the user clicks an item in the list. (The page sees two web parts, and does not know which ribbon to display until one has been clicked.)
- In the master page, with some code to check to see if it is a library:  if(ctx.listTemplate == "101" { ...  }. But for existing sites, this will require an update to each site's master page.

Possible code for a master page.

```
<script>
function TTNAddSiteTitle() {
  if(ctx.listTemplate == "101" ) {
    document.querySelector("#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin",ctx.SiteTitle + " - ");
  }
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("TTNAddSiteTitle");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, that works very well, thanks for the detailed info. One question, if I click on Library settings from the ribbon go to the Library settings page, the site name does not appear there. Could we also make it appear on the library settings page. So currently its like Document Library Name->Settings ---change to---->>>>SiteNAme->Document Library name->Settings.?

Comment: If you were working with on-prem SharePoint you could add the above script to the _layouts/15/listedit.aspx page. As you are using SharePoint Online and cannot directly edit _layouts pages, it would need to be added to the site's master page.

Comment: noticed one thing, I put the code in the master page and its working well and the site name appears on the document library page but on the landing page of any site, the site name appears twice for e.g if the site name is Brick then it would appear as Brick-Brick on the landing page. I only want this functionality to work on the document library pages and lists, is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: A couple of things... The site title is already on the home page. That's why you see two. An IF statement in the master page code can fix that. Originally you said you wanted this for a document library, is the need for every  list and library, every page in the site??? Can you give us a better list of where you want to see this, or maybe a list of where you don't want to see it?

Comment: Sure. Yes for now I only want the site name to appear on the Document library page(this is working fine) and not on the Site's landing page(as the landing page already displays the site title). For future scopes, I wanted to know if this can also be implemented on the SharePoint list page. Thanks.